# @font-face unable to generate the font from the server

Tags: html, url, css, font-face, src

I have looked around online and decided to use the following @font-face implementation:

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: matt;
src: url("/uploads/testing/Interstate-Regular.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype')
     url("/uploads/testing/Interstate-Regular.ttf")  format('truetype');
}
h5.pleasework {
font-family: matt;
font-size:72px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet='in-store-analytics/testingStyle'}" />

</head>
<h1> this is a test </h1>

<img src="/uploads/features/featured-block_inthenumbers.png" alt="Smiley face" height="420" width="420">
<img src="/uploads/testing/awesomeness.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="420" width="420">

<div id="happiness">
    <h5 class="pleasework"> PLEASE WORK FOR ME </h5>
</div>
```

For whatever reason, the font won't generate, but the images do, a result which makes me suspect that the issue lies with the url tag within the src parameter.

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to Chrome dev tools and see if there's a little red cross in the corner. Click on that and it will show you if the fonts are 404ing

Comment: Insufficient information. The URL(s) might be wrong, or the font file(s) might be broken. And why are you using only EOT and TTF formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

*Make sure to put `@font-face` at top of your stylesheet*

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: "Interstate-Regular";  
  src: url(/uploads/testing/Interstate-Regular.eot);
  src: local("Interstate-Regular"), url(/uploads/testing/Interstate-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
} 

h5.pleasework {
font-family: "Interstate-Regular";
font-size:72px;
}
```

However, if you were to use only .tff, then would it would look like this:

```
@font-face {  
      font-family: matt;  
      src: url(/uploads/testing/Interstate-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
    } 

h5.pleasework {
font-family: matt;
font-size:72px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

This site is VERY helpful: (REFER TO SECTIONS: 'How @font-face Works: Easy Peasy' & 'C'mon, is it Really that Simple?'
http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680

Comment: You are a GOD THANK YOU! If I could vote this up 10 times, I would.

Comment: Hoestnly though, I'm not sure why it worked? Could you explain the change please.

Comment: Unfortunately, your method doesn't seem to work for IE and Firefox, but I can work on that.

Comment: I'll let you know if I come across anything that'll help you out. IE can def be a pain :(.